# PyQT5+QMYSQL. App stops working while executing query

Tags: python-3.5, pyqt5

I'm trying to connect to Mysql database through PyQt.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL","mydb")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("test")
db.setUserName("***")
db.setPassword("*******")
ok = db.open()
if not ok: print(db.lastError().text())
else: print("connected")

query = QSqlQuery(db);
ok2 = query.exec_("SELECT * FROM table_one");
if not ok2: print(query.lastError().text())
```

When I'm try to run this code, Python stops working and giving a windows error.

[image]

The problem is 100% in

```
query.exec_("SELECT * FROM table_one");
```

statement. Can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong with my code?
P.S. Windows 7 x64, Python-3.5.2, PyQT-5.6. Error occurs with QMYSQL driver, when I'm trying to run SQLite examples - all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found solution that worked for me:

1. uninstall PyQt-5.6
2. install PyQt-5.7 via pip
3. Put libmysql.dll from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib into the folder with my sсript to get rid of "driver not loaded" error.